# Why switch button (input type="checkbox") works only ones - JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, uibutton, uiswitch

When I use this way - it works only one time and then after clicking stops:

```
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" class="switch5">
<div class="slider round"></div>
</label> 

   $('.switch5').on('click', function() {
          $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "disabled", false );
          $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value", 100 );

    $(this).off('click');

    $(this).on('click', function() {
        $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "disabled", true );
        $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value", 0 );

    });


});
```

When I use seperate buttons for 'on' and 'off' (divs) then it works perfectly - but I would like one switch instead of two buttons:

```
<div class="on-button">ON</div>
<div class="off-button">OFF</div>


$('.on-button').on('click', function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "disabled", false );
    $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value", 100 );
});
$('.off-button').on('click', function() {
    $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "disabled", true );
    $( "#slider" ).slider( "option", "value", 0 );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Your first example fails due to:

`$(this).off('click');`

> The `.off()` method removes event handlers that were attached with `.on()`.

So after the first click, the `.off()` removes the bound callback; therefore, there is no callback function assigned to the `click` event on your checkbox element. It only works the 1 time.

**Update 1**

Here's an example of what you might want to consider: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/23L6hb63/

**HTML**

```
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" class="switch5">
  <div class="slider round"></div>
</label>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $(".slider").slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 1,
    range: "min",
    change: function(e, ui) {
      $(".switch5").val(ui.value)
      if (ui.value < 1) {
        $(".switch5").prop("checked", false);
      } else {
        $(".switch5").prop("checked", true);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**Update 2**

Based on my confusion and your new example, I would suggest the following:

```
  $('.switch5').on('click', function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $("#slider").slider("option", {
        disabled: false,
        value: 100
      });
    } else {
      $("#slider").slider("option", {
        disabled: true,
        value: 0
      });
    }
  });
```

Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/uz1noyt0/

Comment: Thx for your answer but I would like to use it  with my css switch: and here it works only ones: [https://jsfiddle.net/mike1mikee/uk764kj1/](https://jsfiddle.net/mike1mikee/uk764kj1/)

Comment: When you click it, you want the slider to become enabled, correct?

Comment: yes, and then click it and disable, but when you check it it works only for one time: 1. first click = enable. 2. sec click = disable. 3. 3rd click = enable and so on, but it works only till 'sec click' . Is it possible? What do you think?

Comment: Twisty you are the best!! Thank you very much! : ]

Comment: @MikeMikee Glad that appears to work or you. If this answers your question, feel free to upvote it and mark it as the answer.